# Does MapKit provide elevation data?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I am working on the iOS app that uses Apple's [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/) and I need to obtain elevation change from **Point A** to **Point B**.

I do know that [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/altitude) has an `altitude` property but it will only give you an altitude based on your current location, whereas I need to get a range of altitude points from one location to the next location.

Similar to this web app that uses Google Maps + Google Elevation API:

**http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/elevation/elevation-profile.html**

Comment: Elevation data is now part of the API, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39102624/386738)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting location in air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102169/detecting-location-in-air)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapKit won't give you this, but you could use the [free MapQuest API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/elevation-service).

Answer (score 1):

MapKit doesn't provide altitude information for a given point. If you'd like to create your own api, see [Global Elevation Datasets](http://vterrain.org/Elevation/global.html).