# Detecting location in air

Tags: ios, swift, location

In my app location should be detected by my mobile when i am in air. Is it possible to detect location using google or Apple map? If anyone of you faced this scenario please give me some solution.

Comment: Seems to have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28352711/1971013) Did you search well before posting?

Comment: @meaning-matters The answers of that question seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading [Google Maps Elevation API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro).
The example JSON returns this:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So, you have to look for the **elevation** attribute. Then, you ask if elevation is higher than **X** (Where X is the needed altitude to consider the  user is in air), and you're done.

Comment: All the Google API can do is give the ground level at the current location. What is 'X' here and how would this work???